# Set/update inheritance flag permission on file/folder using C# error "No flags can be set. Parameter name: inheritanceFlags"

Tags: c#, inheritance, permissions, flags

I am creating a program that takes a text file containing permissions and applies those permissions to files/folders.
When I try to change the inheritance flags to either ContainerInherit or ObjectInherit I keep getting an error "No flags can be set. Parameter name: inheritanceFlags".
I don't get this error if I set the inheritance flag to None. This is my code:

```
if (flag.Equals("None"))
{
    inheritFlag = InheritanceFlags.None;
}
else if (flag.Equals("ContainerInherit"))
{
    inheritFlag = InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit;
}
else if (flag.Equals("ObjectInherit"))
{
    inheritFlag = InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit;
}                          

FileSystemAccessRule fsarule = new FileSystemAccessRule(user, fileSysRight, inheritFlag, propFlag, controlType);
fileSec.AddAccessRule(fsarule);
File.SetAccessControl(currentFilePath, fileSec);
```

How do I set the inheritance flags without getting this error?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

use DirectorySecurity class instead File Class Because inheritence on a file doesn't exist. It's only accepted to directories and child directories and files. I editted your code like this:

```
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
DirectorySecurity dirSecurity = dirInfo.GetAccessControl();
dirSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(user, fileSysRight, inheritFlag, propFlag, controlType);
dirSecurity.SetAccessControl(currentFilePath, fileSec);
```